# Error en app Google Maps en Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, phonegap, apache-cordova

Estoy realizando una app en apache cordova y quiero implementar la api de google maps ya la tengo habilitada pero no me funciona, al momento de visualizarla no se ve nada.

1.- Instale el plugin de google maps con estos comandos:
        cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps

2.- En mi archivo config.xml le agregue esto:

```
<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="...." />
<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="..." />
```

(con mi correspondiente API).

3.- Y hize el siguiente ejemplo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
          var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

          // Create a Google Maps native view under the map_canvas div.
          var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);

          // If you click the button, do something...
          var button = document.getElementById("button");
          button.addEventListener("click", function() {

            // Move to the position with animation
            map.animateCamera({
              target: {lat: 37.422359, lng: -122.084344},
              zoom: 17,
              tilt: 60,
              bearing: 140,
              duration: 5000
            });

            // Add a maker
            var marker = map.addMarker({
              position: {lat: 37.422359, lng: -122.084344},
              title: "Welecome to \n" +
                     "Cordova GoogleMaps plugin for iOS and Android",
              snippet: "This plugin is awesome!",
              animation: plugin.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            });

            // Show the info window
            marker.showInfoWindow();

          });

        }, false);

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #map_canvas { /* Must bigger size than 100x100 pixels */
          width: 100%;
          height: 500px;
        }
        button {
          padding: .5em;
          margin: .5em;
        }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <div id="map_canvas">
          <button id="button">Click me!</button>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: se ve normal, si instalaste las google play services sdk ?

Comment: No no las use, habra un tutorial para que las agregue

Comment: En el mismo plugin estan los requerimientos para hacerlo funcionar. 
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps
Y las guias
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.3.0/README.md

Ocupas instalar las google play services sdk para que cordova obtenga lo del mapa

Comment: Bien yo lo checo, gracias